# how to set proxy authentication with adb

Tags: adb

how to set proxy authentication with adb

I tried

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy 192.168.225.100:3128
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_host 192.168.225.100
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_port 3128
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_username foo
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_password bar
```

but it not working